# "killall wpa_supplicant" affects "ip route add ..." in a strange way

Tags: linux, bash, networking, wpa

Not sure if the title explains my situation correctly, but in details it looks like this:

I'm writing a simple bash script to set up a wireless network, using wlp2s0 interface.

```
ip route flush dev wlp2s0
ip addr flush dev wlp2s0
ip link set wlp2s0 down

killall wpa_supplicant

ip link set wlp2s0 up
ip addr add 192.168.1.200/24 dev wlp2s0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1

wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlp2s0 -c wireless.conf
```

It kills all previously started wpa_supplicants and then starts a new one.
Now, the problem is that the `killall` call causes `ip route add` to cry:

> RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable

no matter if wpa_supplicant was actually started before.

It can be "fixed" by adding a `sleep 1` call after `killall`, but of course I'd like to avoid this. It can also be fixed by removing the `killall` command and calling it manually before the script.

So the question is - how can I work around this strange behaviour of `killall`? Maybe someone has any idea why are these strange things happening.

EDIT: `ip route add` does not give that error if `killall` isn't called before it.

Comment: Does `ip route add` say this too, when called without calling `killall` before?

Comment: No, it works as expected if `killall` is not called before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you think it was strange?  Successful return of `killall` doesn't necessarily mean `wpa_supplicant` has finished processing the incoming `SIGTERM` signal.  It's only that the signal was delivered to the `wpa_supplicant` process, at best.  Pehaps `wpa_supplicant` needed some more time (such as `sleep 1`) to finish execution of its clean-up handler (`wpa_supplicant_terminate_proc()` in `wpa_supplicant.c`)

- http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/src/utils/eloop.c#n753
- http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.c#n4033

So, I think you really need `sleep 1`.

### Update

I always rely on polling method like this

```
TIMEO=5
for ((i=0; i<TIMEO; ++i)); do
    if pidof -s wpa_supplicant > /dev/null; then
        sleep 1
    else
        break
    fi
done

if ((TIMEO==i)); then
    echo "timeout"
else
    echo "it's gone"
fi
```

assuming there will not be multiple instances of `wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for such detalied explanation. Well, it's getting a bit off-topic, but is there a "good" way to wait for the actual process termination, instad of `sleep 1`?

Comment: @ValeriyStreltsov See my update.  But it is nothing more than a sophisticated way of doing `sleep 1` ...

Comment: You can do `wait $(pidof -s wpa_supplicant)` instead of polling